# Windows Hiding Folders

Tags: windows, ntfs

Has anyone noticed that after certain actions, a Windows folder will just go hidden?  Like its been entirely removed from the taxonomy of the file system, but is still accessible if you type in the exact path?

Does anyone know how to remedy this?

Comment: Is this on a server or...as worded, this might get migrated to SuperUser. Are you talking about a share or a local folder? What version(s) of Windows?

Comment: And after *what* actions? I notice they go hidden if I set the hidden flag :-)

Comment: Its on a Server yes.  Its only invisible locally on the server too.  And its if I browse to the root folder, its not visible at all from any microsoft tools, but if you use a non-microsoft tool, its visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the system and hidden flags were set

This is remedied by entering the command

```
attrib FOLDER -h -s
```